# Converting image object to File object, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to convert "image object" to "File object" using HTML5 in client side to upload the File to the azure blob storage.

Since I'm using AngularJs, my plan is to

- convert image to file
- upload file to blob storage using [angular-azure-blob-upload](https://github.com/kinstephen/angular-azure-blob-upload)

I have found lots of examples that convert File object to image using FileReader, but I can't find the opposite example.

I heard it is impossible to write files to local file system with client javascript, but I don't need to **store** the File, I just need the file object reference to upload the file.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use fetch and FormData to convert and upload.

```
//load src and convert to a File instance object
//work for any type of src, not only image src.
//return a promise that resolves with a File instance
function srcToFile(src, fileName, mimeType){
    return (fetch(src)
        .then(function(res){return res.arrayBuffer();})
        .then(function(buf){return new File([buf], fileName, {type:mimeType});})
    );
}

//usage example: (works in Chrome and Firefox)
//convert src to File and upload to server php
srcToFile('/images/logo.png', 'new.png', 'image/png')
.then(function(file){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file1', file);
    return fetch('/upload.php', {method:'POST', body:fd});
})
.then(function(res){
    return res.text();
})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
;
```

For your case, just replace **`'/images/logo.png'`** with **`imageObject.src`**

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to save files to the local file system, through the File System API, but only Chrome and Opera supports it. If you want to render an image file from File/Blob to an IMG tag, you can do

```
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(myFileOrBlob);
```

This will convert the File/Blob to an URL, which is available only inside of your browser and looks like that

```
blob:http%3A//localhost/2ee59cd6-9220-429c-add9-05983645639e
```

After you are done using the image, it's good to free the memory by doing

```
URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
```

Hope I understood you correctly and that helps you.

Comment: blobURL is for local use and should not be uploaded to server.